# Window.close not working on android in app browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, viber

Is there a way to close the in app browser? `window.close` is only working on iOS device, and it doesn't work in Android. I've tried using `window.top.close` and `window.open("","_self") window.close` and none of it is working. I've tried to look for which browser does Viber and Line use internally but they don't have any documentation

Comment: I have added an answer. I hope It will help you, have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var win=window.open( "myurl", "_blank");
win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function(){
       var loop = window.setInterval(function(){
           win.executeScript({
                   code: "window.shouldClose"
               },
               function(values){
                   if(values[0]){
                     win.close();
                     window.clearInterval(loop);
                   }
               }
           );
       },100);
   });
```

In your called window, simply do this, When you want to close it

```
window.shouldClose=true
```

Comment: That's the same with window.open("","_self") then window.close and it will not work

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this just for future references. You can set `window.location.href` to Viber deep link like `viber://pa?chatURI=<URI>` to navigate back to chat window. Here is the [doc page](https://developers.viber.com/docs/tools/deep-links/).